# Django Simple Jwt Authenticate multiple models

Tags: django, authentication, websocket, jwt, django-channels

I'm working on a project that includes users communicating with devices( rpi's) via websockets. They only way I can think to make it more secure so other's can't access a websocket 'room' they aren't allowed to be in, is to have a separate way for the rpi's to login like users do. Then somehow check if they are authenticated when connecting to a socket room. Any tips for how to do this?

Comment: do you store mapping whether user is allowed in a group or not?

Comment: I'm using django channels for the socket connections. Left alone ANY device or user, authenticated or not authenticated can join the room and view data. However is I use user authentication then I won't be able to connect any of the raspberry pi's to the room.